# AndEngine FPS Drops With Each Sprite

Tags: sprite, andengine, frame-rate

I am working with AndEngine for an app project and I have hit a major snag in regards to my frame rate.  I have a few decently sized sprites to place on the screen, each being 512x768, and it seems that each one of these I add takes a very noticeable chunk of my FPS away.

Even if the image being used is nothing but a blank PNG, there is an equivalent amount of loss.  I have searched around and tried everything that made sense, but nothing seems to have improved it at all, and the lack of documentation for AndEngine doesn't simplify matters any.

My only real guess at the reason is that the sprites must be entirely recreating themselves every call.  I could be entirely wrong, but it's the only logical reason I can think of.  Despite that, I am not sure how to stop this from happening (Still assuming it is the problem at all of course).

The code I am using to create everything is the same as every example I've seen, so I doubt that is the problem, but just in case my sprites are setup more or less like the following :

```
        public void onLoadResources(){
            this.mTexAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
            this.mTexBottom = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexAtlas, this, "bottom.png", 0, 0);
            this.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexAtlas);
        }

        public Scene onLoadScene(){
            mTexBottom = new Sprite(spriteX, spriteY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, mTexAtlas);
            scene.attachChild(mTexBottom, childCount++);
        }
```

It's not my exact code, for clarity reasons, but that is how all of the examples I have seen look, so that's pretty much how mine looks.  Oh, and the texture atlas is 1024 wide because I am putting two images on each, at least for right now.

At this point I am willing to try anything to get it going a little better, so any ideas at all would be great.

Comment: Looks like you're using the entire TextureAtlas as the image source for the Sprite. A couple 1024x1024 sprites are heavy.

Comment: Ah right, my code example was a little off as I was trying to keep it bare minimum, the texture atlas is actually split in half, each half representing one of the textures.  I do realize they are still rather large images, but each one of these (I am using four at the moment) is taking another 5+ FPS from me, which seems a bit extreme.  If there is a completely different route to try I'd be happy to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong variables in the wrong places, could you try it like this?

```
    public void onLoadResources(){
        this.mTexAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        this.mTexBottom = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexAtlas, this, "bottom.png", 0, 0);
        this.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexAtlas);
    }

    public Scene onLoadScene(){
        Sprite theSprite = new Sprite(spriteX, spriteY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, mTexBottom );
        scene.attachChild(theSprite, childCount++);
    }
```

Comment: Gah!  That was my bad again.  Apparently I was a little out of it while throwing together the example code, and I do actually have it as you described.  I updated the code to be a tad more accurate in that regard, but I'm also going on 30 hours of being awake, so hopefully it's all there.  Even if I can't find the proper solution to making the sprites not devour the hell out of my I would not mind being able to, after an occasional bit of processing, combine all of them together into one, as then it should only take the performance hit once instead of 4+ times.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your Camera? I mean how big are your Sprites compared to the screen?

You should try to avoid drawing the screen more than once. Drawing a couple of Sprites that cover the whole screen is probably the worst thing you could do.

Comment: Well in regards to the size of the camera, I should mention that the project is a live wallpaper, and the camera does scroll around a little, so it's a rather big area.  These sprites that are causing the issue can be set to different scales, and there is a difference in FPS based on their size.  At their biggest, which does fill up most of the screen when you're on the middle homescreen, it's at about 28FPS with everything going, and at their smallest, which is only an inch or two squared on the screen, it goes up to 35 or so.  If I remove only those four sprites I go up over 50 easily.